# InstantiationException when constructing an object that implements the List interface

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I have an old code that clones different objects. `list` is declared as **java.util.List**

```
CloneUtils.cloneList(list);
```

Inside the `cloneList` looks like this:

```
public static List cloneList(final List list) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    List list2;
    try {
        list2 = list.getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.debug(e);
        list2 = new ArrayList();
    }
```

The call to `cloneList` throws an exception:

```
jvm 1    | DEBUG[2012-10-09 16:57:58,611]: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
jvm 1    | java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
jvm 1    |      at com.acme.common.util.CloneUtils.cloneList(CloneUtils.java:
88)
jvm 1    |      at com.acme.common.data.PropertyDescriptor.clone(PropertyDesc
riptor.java:165)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMet
hodAccessorImpl.java:25)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Is it possible to create a new object with the same type as the one passed to the `cloneList` method using reflection?

**Edit1**

The `list` argument that is passed to the `cloneList` method is obtained from:

```
String[] fields = field.split(",");
list = Arrays.asList(fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation `Arrays.asList(String[]);` return **Arrays.ArrayList**, not java.util.ArrayList.

See the asList implementation,

```
   public static <T> List<T> asList(final T... a)
   {
     return new Arrays.ArrayList(a);
   }
```

Arrays.ArrayList is static inner class inside ArraysClass

```
 private static final class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> 
     implements Serializable, RandomAccess
  {
  ..
  ..
```

But what I don't understand is the intention of such operation( cloning the list in a different way).

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html) of `Arrays$ArrayList` - it seems the class does not have an empty constructor, thus you cannot instantiate it with an empty `newInstance()`

Note that the class you are getting the exception from is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` and NOT [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

The problem with reflection is - you don't know exactly how to instantiate *all* objects - so building an "all cases instantiation" is pretty much impossible, unless you have some guiding rules on which constructors must be implemented.

An alternative, that might be possible in most cases is to use the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) instead of reflection to create new objects, but I doubt you can use it here without more modifications I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the original object's class has a no-args constructor then this will work. (The ArrayList DOES have a no-args constructor and will work fine with this)

```
static Object makeSameType(Object original) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> originalClass = original.getClass();
        Constructor<?> con = originalClass.getConstructor();
        return con.newInstance();
    }
```

Comment: Check closer: it is `Arrays.ArrayList` -- the one obtained by `Arrays.asList`. It has no nullary constructor.